# Variables mysteriously undefined in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, scope, maps, coordinates, undefined

I want to make a request to a weather server using latitudes and longitudes, I have no problem with getting the latitude and longitude - it shows up appended perfectly in my HTML. The mysterious thing is that when I try to use the latitude and longitude variables for the server request and console.log() they are undefined. They should be defined since `window.property` makes the variable `property` global scope. Have a look at the code:

```
function getLocation(){
    if (navigator.geolocation) {
        navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition); //Runs the function "showPosition()"
    }
    else {
        locationDisplay.innerHTML = "Could not find your location, please enter one manually.";
    }
}

function showPosition(position){
    window.latitude = Math.floor(position.coords.latitude); //latitude as integer
    window.longitude = Math.floor(position.coords.longitude); //longitude as integer

    locationDisplay.innerHTML = "Latitude: " + window.latitude + "<br> Longitude: " + window.longitude;
} //.innerHTML adds the coordinates to a div called locationDisplay

getLocation();
console.log(window.latitude + " " + window.longitude);
```

Another just slightly related question: would it be accurate enough for weather services to describe the position in latitude and longitude integers or should I use some decimal points?

Comment: Decimals matter. Play around with this: http://earthexplorer.usgs.gov/

Answer (score 1):

`navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(showPosition);` doesn't run the `showPosition` function.

You are passing that as a success callback method to `navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition` . (Which is a asynchronous call).

`showPosition` will execute after the success of `getCurrentPosition` function. Whereas `console.log(window.latitude + " " + window.longitude);` tries to get the `window.latitude and window.longitude` values before `getCurrentPosition` finishes it's task. At that point of time both the variables are undefined only.

**To avoid this, a quick workaround would be**

use `setTimeout or setInterval` to wait for getCurrentPosition to respond. or set those global variables outside of `showPosition` function with a default value.

Comment: I see. Wouldn't it be possible to create a callback function manually which would then do the console.log() if the getCurrentPosition() was successful? Seems better than guessing on how long of a delay to use.